# Функция имеет неправильный возвращаемый тип

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl

Есть код типа такого:

```
class A
{
    void Foo() { }
    async void FooAsync() => await Task.Run(Foo);
}
```

Пишет ошибку: "void A.foo()" имеет неправильный возвращаемый тип. Убей не понимаю в чем дело... [Вот же](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) есть параметр Action у Task.Run. Откуда ошибка берется???

Comment: @Monk Task.Run и возвращает Task как бы.

Comment: приведение к `Action` должно помочь `Task.Run((Action)Foo)`

Comment: @Grundy точно! Спасибо помогло. Странновато что оно само его не распознало только...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор C# не умеет правильно выбирать тип делегата в случае неявного приведения типа к делегату и перегрузки метода с разными параметрами-делегатами.

Конкретно в данном случае, компилятор ошибочно выбирает перегрузку, принимающую `Func<Task>` или `Func<T>`.

Для того, чтобы обойти такое поведение, можно использовать

- явное приведение типа: `await Task.Run((Action)Foo)`
- явное создание делегата: `await Task.Run(new Action(Foo))`
- или лямбда-выражение: `await Task.Run(() => Foo())`

PS Нет смысла делать методы, состоящие из единственного оператора `await`. Можно было бы убрать слова `async` и `await` - ничего бы не поменялось.

Comment: метод будет выполнен асинхронно. Как же нет смысла то? В этом и смысл.

Comment: @DarkByte асинхронность достигается вызовом `Task.Run`, а не ключевым словом `async`. Ключевое слово `async` само по себе ничего не делает, оно лишь разрешает использовать `await`.

Comment: я то это понимаю. Но у меня и есть вызов Task.Run вообще то... Или вы готовы поспорить что эта функция не выполниться асинхронно? Это просто асинхронная обертка одной функции над другой. Такие вещи есть даже в .NET.

Comment: @DarkByte асинхронной называется любая функция, которая продолжает работать после того как вернет управление, независимо от наличия или отсутствия ключевого слова `async`.

Comment: тут вы не правы. Без ключевого слова async не может быть асинхронной функции.

Comment: Если просто взять и вызвать Task.Run без await то он заблокирует вызывающий поток до завершения работы.

Comment: @DarkByte откуда такие мысли? `Task.Run` делает прямо противоположное!

Comment: а ну да, вроде не блокирует проверил. Ну а для чего тогда нужны async / await если и без них можно? Возврат значений удобнее?

Comment: @DarkByte оператор `await` довольно удобен когда он не является последним оператором в методе. Или когда их два.